# How to copy google doc to another folder in google drive service

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a class that makes a copy of a google doc template file to then merge placeholders with data.  The problem is that it's creating the copy in the same folder as the original template file and I can't find a way to copy it to another folder.

Say I have a structure like so in google drive.

```
Main
    TemplateFiles
        MainTemplateDoc
    Contracts
        CopyOfMainTemplateDocAfterBeingMerged
```

As you can see, the CopyOfMainTemplateDocAfterBeingMerged doc wouldn't be located in the TemplateFiles folder where the original template was, but copied to the Contracts folder.

Is it possible to use the google drive v2 service to move the file after creating the copy?  I'm using the .net Google.Apis.Drive.v2 nuget package.  Here's the code that I have so far to create the copy.

```
private string CopyDocument(string documentId, string title)
{
    var newFile = new File { Title = title };
    var documentCopyFile = driveService.Files.Copy(newFile, documentId).Execute();
    return documentCopyFile.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using Drive API v2.
- You want to copy a file to the folder of `Contracts`.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### From:

```
var newFile = new File { Title = title };
```

#### To:

```
var newFile = new File {
    Title = title,
    Parents = new List<ParentReference> {new ParentReference {Id = parentId}}
};
```

or

```
var newFile = new File() {
    Title = title
};
newFile.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() {new ParentReference() {Id = parentId}};
```

or

```
var newFile = new File();
newFile.Title = title;
newFile.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() {new ParentReference() {Id = parentId}};
```

- `parentId` is the folder ID of the folder `Contracts`.

#### Note:

- If you want to use Drive API v3, please use `new List<string> {folderId}` instead of `new List<ParentReference> {new ParentReference {Id = folderId}}`.

#### References:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)
- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you.  I did find the parents reference using an updaterequest, but couldn't get it working.  It worked fine here so I'm not quite sure what the issue was, but hey, it's working.  Thanks again!

Comment: @geoff swartz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.